# How do you calculate an expiration date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to calculate an expiration date.  Should be pretty easy right?  Well, my "lifespan" is in years, not days, and to make it more challenging, the years value can be fractional.  Here is what I am starting with:

```
set @ExpirationDate = DATEADD(year, @LifeSpanYears, @BeginDate)
```

The problem is, [DATEADD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) allows a decimal to be passed in, but if you read the documentation, the decimal is truncated to an int.

**How do you calculate an expiration date with a fractional year?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the answer I came up with:

```
create function Reporting.CalcExpirationDate ( @LifeSpanYears decimal(9,2), @BeginDate date)
returns date
begin
    return DATEADD(day, (@LifeSpanYears * 365.25), @BeginDate)
end
```

Then use it like this:

```
          select Reporting.CalcExpirationDate (13   , '2015-09-01') as CalculatedDate, '2028-09-01' as ExpectedDate
union all select Reporting.CalcExpirationDate (13.5 , '2015-09-01') as CalculatedDate, '2029-03-01' as ExpectedDate
```

Notes: As I was working on this I realized that it is impossible to determine the exact expiration date using a fractional year as a lifespan.  How do you know when to add leap days or not?  If you really want the exact answer, you need lifespan in days.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, the "lifespan in years" is probably a lifespan in months.  If so, you might consider:

```
return dateadd(month, round(@LIfeSpanYears * 12, 0), @BeginDate)
```

This handles the issue with leap years.  However, it comes at the cost of only resolving to months.

Comment: You know what I could do also?  I could separate the integer and fractional part of the LifeSpanYears.  Add the fractional number of days using my answer, then add the integer number of years which would handle leap years.  The answer is still not deterministic because I'm not even sure what the answer *should* be.  :)

Comment: @Jess . . . That would come close.  It wouldn't handle situation where the days cross a leap year boundary, but you would be off by at most one day.